# Curl request in docker container succeeds where it should fail

Tags: docker, curl, certificate, tls1.2

Example test URL: https://6195.playfabapi.com/swagger. Certificate chain for this site: Starfield etc -> Starfield etc -> Amazon Root CA 1 -> Amazon -> *.playfabapi.com

Windows Server 2019 running a Windows Server 2019 docker container (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.17763.973)

PowerShell commands executed on docker container:

```
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\* -Recurse | where {$_.Subject –like '*Starfield*'}
(no results)
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\* -Recurse | where {$_.Subject –like '*Amazon*'}
(No results)
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\* -Recurse | where {$_.Subject –like '*PlayFab*'}
(No results)
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\* -Recurse | where {$_.Subject –like '*'}
(About a dozen results, that all seem to be Microsoft-issued certificates)
curl --ssl-reqd --tlsv1.2 https://6195.playfabapi.com/swagger
(Successful json blob)
```

My Question:
Why is the curl command successful? Everything I understand about Docker and certificates and curl says that curl command should fail with a certificate error (likely not trusted or something).

I found a similar but inverted question: [SSL certificate verification fails inside docker container on specific server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970990/ssl-certificate-verification-fails-inside-docker-container-on-specific-server). How do I do the inverse, make the docker container isolated, and force it to validate only on its own certificates?

Comment: I don't want to network-isolate the container as it needs to host connections to the open internet. But I do want to strictly control the list of certificates it validates (or not), independent of the metal machine that the container happens to be running on.

Answer (score 0):

curl.exe version 7.71.1 on Windows doesn't yet use the Windows certificate store, but rather an internal certificate store, or an explicit cert file via --cacert option.

[Configure cURL to use default system cert store on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551409/configure-curl-to-use-default-system-cert-store-on-windows)
That suggests that it's possible with the library, but it's not a default option anywhere (for now).