# Problems installing csvtk with Docker using debian:stretch-slim

Tags: docker, debian-stretch

I am a newbie to Docker and I am trying to install `csvtk` via Docker using `debian:stretch-slim`.

This below is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    jq                 \
    perl               \
    python3            \
    wget               \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -qO- https://github.com/shenwei356/csvtk/releases/download/v0.23.0/csvtk_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar -xz \
     && cp csvtk /usr/local/bin/
```

It fails at the `csvtk` step with the below error message:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN wget -qO- https://github.com/shenwei356/csvtk/releases/download/v0.23.0/csvtk_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar -xz      && cp csvtk /usr/local/bin/
 ---> Running in 0f3a0e75a5de

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -qO- https://github.com/shenwei356/csvtk/releases/download/v0.23.0/csvtk_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar -xz      && cp csvtk /usr/local/bin/' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` was exiting with error code meaning 5 SSL verification failed on wget. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971185/4676641), you just needed to install `ca-certificates` before `wget`.

This Dockerfile should build successfully:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    jq                 \
    perl               \
    python3            \
    wget               \
    # added this package to help with ssl certs in Docker
    ca-certificates    \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -qO- https://github.com/shenwei356/csvtk/releases/download/v0.23.0/csvtk_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar -xz \
     && cp csvtk /usr/local/bin/
```

As a general tip when debugging issues like these, it's likely easiest to remove the offending `RUN` line from your Dockerfile and then try building and running the container in a shell and manually executing the commands you want. Like this:

```sh
docker build -t test:v1 .
docker run --rm -it test:v1 /bin/bash
# run commands manually and check the full error output
```

While combining different `RUN` instructions with `&&` is best practice to reduce the number of image layers, it's difficult to debug when building.